# How use crosstab with apply or sapply function

Tags: r, pivot-table, apply, sapply

I am struggling with using the `crosstab` function, available at the link:

```
source("http://pcwww.liv.ac.uk/~william/R/crosstab.r")
```

I have also used the `gtsummary` library and converted `mtcars` to a tibble, then converted the `vs` and `am` columns to characters using:

```
library(gtsummary)
mtcars = mtcars %>% as_tibble()
mtcars = apply(mtcars %>% select(vs, am), 2, as.character)

crosstab(mtcars, row.vars = "vs")
crosstab(mtcars, row.vars = "am")
```

I would like to achieve the same using the `apply` or `sapply` function, without using the `crosstab` function's `row.vars` argument, which I do not know how to set.

I have tried

```
apply(mtcars, 2, crosstab(mtcars, row.vars = c('vs', 'am')))
```

But it does not work. Is there an alternative way to achieve this, even with the `sapply` function?

Thanks.

Comment: what is your desired output? can you edit the question and add an example?

Comment: yes. Please check what returns the function separately on the interested variable. I have edited the post

Comment: great can you check if the answer suits your needs?

Comment: it really does. Thanks could you explain a bit about the utility of the `\` mark?

Comment: single quotation marks (') function the same as double ones (") in this case . They can be useful if you have one type of quotation in a sting , ie 'a string with "aqoute" inside'

Comment: sorry, there was this missing symbol within those \. I do know why it was converted like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you almost got it right, you just got confused with the apply syntax:

You want to iterate over a list of column names (variables) instead of the dataframe and pass this as the row.vars argument.

```
lapply(c('vs', 'am'),\(col) crosstab(mtcars, row.vars = col))
sapply(c('vs', 'am'),\(col) crosstab(mtcars, row.vars = col),simplify = F)
```

The equivalent for loop would be:

```
for (col in c('vs', 'am')) {
  crosstab(mtcars,row.vars = col)|>print()
}
```